# no cambia el textarea una vez escrito

Tags: javascript, html

tengo un textarea, digamos que es un diagnostico de un ordenador de un cliente lo que va dentro, yo tengo un pantalla con varios clientes, cuando pulso en uno, carga una ventana nueva que lee los datos desde un ajax a una base de datos y pone el texto en ese textarea. Asta ahí todo correcto.
el problema que tengo es que si escribo texto en ese textarea y guardo en la base de datos esa información, el text area, cuando cambio de cliente, no cambia el texto...
desde el inspector veo que cuando escribo, el dom no cambia...
he probado el mismo ejemplo desde https://liveweave.com/ y si funciona...

```js
var dietaac="b";

    var die=document.getElementById('resumenponeradieta');
    console.log("dieta: |"+dietaac+"|");
    //die.innerHTML="";
    if(dietaac==""){
        die.innerHTML="";
    }
    else{
        die.innerHTML=dietaac;
    }
    
    
   document.getElementById("guardarcambiospaciente").onclick=function(){
      var die=document.getElementById('resumenponeradieta');
    console.log("dieta: |"+dietaac+"|");
    //die.innerHTML="";
    if(dietaac==""){
        die.innerHTML="";
    }
    else{
        die.innerHTML=dietaac;
    }
   }
```

```html
<textarea id="resumenponeradieta" class=" coltextoresumenes disescrolldiag "></textarea>

<div id="guardarcambiospaciente" class="colguardarcambios2 mododedo">GUARDAR CAMBIOS</div>
```

en ese ejemplo de codigo muestro lo que quiero decir, si hay texto en la variable dietaac, muestra ese texto, pero si escribo encima del textarea, y cambio el valor de la variable (o le doy a guardar cambios), no me cambia el textarea...

seguro que es una tonteria pero no doy con la tecla...

Comment: Para modificar el **valor** de un campo de formulario (o área de texto) se usa el atributo `value` y no `innerHTML`.

Comment: hice pruebas con .value y parece que ya me lo cambia bien. gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que para modificar el textarea, tienes que usar la propiedad value.
Hice algunos ajustes a tu código.

```js
var dietaac="b";

let die=document.getElementById('resumenponeradieta');
console.log("dieta: |"+dietaac+"|");
if(dietaac==""){
  die.innerHTML="";
}
else{
  die.innerHTML=dietaac;
}

document.getElementById("guardarcambiospaciente").onclick=function(){
  let die=document.getElementById('resumenponeradieta');
  dietaac = die.value;
  console.log("dieta: |"+dietaac+"|");
}
```

```html
<textarea id="resumenponeradieta" class=" coltextoresumenes disescrolldiag "></textarea>

<div id="guardarcambiospaciente" class="colguardarcambios2 mododedo">GUARDAR CAMBIOS</div>
```